# Why isn't my client receiving my file from the server?

Tags: python, networking, server

I've created a fairly simple server with the aim of sending a simple .txt file but it won't send for some reason.

Server code:

```
import socket

port = 8081
host = "192.168.0.20"
s = socket.socket()
s.bind((host, port))

s.listen(5)

print("Server Listening.....")

while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print("Got connection from", addr)
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    print("Data recieved", repr(data))

    filename = "/Users/dylanrichards/Desktop/keysyms.txt"
    f = open(filename, 'rb')
    l = f.read(1024)
    while (l):
        conn.send(l)
        print("Sent", repr(l))
        l = f.read(1024)
    f.close()

    print("Done sending")
    conn.send("Thank you for connecting")
    conn.close()
```

Here is the code for the client:

```
import socket

port = 8081
host = "192.168.0.20"
s = socket.socket()
s.connect((host, port))

with open("Recieved_File", 'wb') as f:
    print("File opened")
    while True:
        print("Receiving data...")
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print("Data=%s",  (data))
        if not data:
            break
        f = open("/Users/dylanrichards/Desktop/test12.txt")
        f.write(data)

f.close()
print("Successfully got file")
print("Connection closed")
s.close()
```

Im testing this over my Local Network on a Macbook Air if thats any help. Thanks in advance...

Comment: I would try to change the port number. if it works, well, that's because the previous port was already allocated.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, that was I thought the solution might be, but I've tried that numerous times to no avail

Comment: okay, let the network experts answer. I don't qualify :) can you be more specific: is the client not sending, or the server not recieving?

Comment: BTW there's a problem in your reception: you're opening `test12.txt` in `read` mode (overwriting yor `f` from `Received_File`) and write to it. That's bogus.

Comment: OK, so I've just noticed its not the networking. A file is created on my Desktop like its meant to but with none of the data that its meant to have.

Comment: so, problem fixed with the file stuff fixed?

Comment: Not yet. The file is being sent to my Desktop as planned but the data isnt being wrote to it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Multiple file handles opened and all has same variable `f`
2. `with open("Recieved_File", 'wb') as f:` -- I think this is not required.
3. `f = open("/Users/dylanrichards/Desktop/test12.txt")`should be outside `while` loop.
4. While opening above file, add mode as 'wb'

**Client Code** :

```
import socket

port = 8081
host = "192.168.0.20"
s = socket.socket()
s.connect((host, port))

f = open("/Users/dylanrichards/Desktop/test12.txt",'wb')
while True:
    print("Receiving data...")
    data = s.recv(1024)

    if not data:
        break
    print("Data=%s",  (data))
    f.write(data)

f.close()
print("Successfully got file")
print("Connection closed")
s.close()
```

Comment: I've tried your code and still the data isn't being written to the designated file. Is there a problem with the server code?

Comment: Yes, in fact, your server only gives the content of the file when it has received some data ;)

Comment: Just add: s.send(bytes('Hello', 'utf-8'))
Before the connect on the client side ;)

Comment: Or try to remove the `data = conn.recv(1024)` line from the server. It waits for some data from the client. However, your client was never sending any data, so, this line was blocking everything.